# octopress's date_format not working

Tags: date-format, octopress

I comment the original data_format in `_config.yml`  and have set the date format to another one(I tried several date format):

```
date_format: "%F %a"        #2012-01-01    
#date_format: "ordinal"
```

I `rake generate` and `rake preview`/or `rake deploy`, I still saw the date format is showing like "OCT 18TH, 2014 7:37 PM"  , why is that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**First solution:**

As far as I found the `date_format` parameter from `_config.yml` file is obsolete (I reported it in https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1697) because the previous Octopress date plugin was replaced with Jekyll Date Format. The parameter is no longer used.

To change date format on your blog you have to edit `source/_includes/post/date.html` file. You just need to replace two occurrences of

`{{ page.date_time_html }}`

with the

`{{ post.date | date: "%F" }}`

Of course you can change the `%F` as you want. More about Jekyll Date Format you can find at: http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples

---

**Second solution:**

I have checked the issue once again and now it works as it should. You do not need replace `{{ page.date_time_html }}` any more. Just follow the configuration of the Octopress Date Format plugin: https://github.com/octopress/date-format#configuration.

You need to add second option - `time_format` - for time formatting and everything should works properly.

Example:

`date_format: "%Y-%m-%d"  # e.g. 2014-07-03
time_format: "%H:%M"     # 24 hour time`

---

**Summary:**

Octopress is constantly developed project and the date format issue will probably be different on different commits at GitHub.

Comment: I wondered, which one is so called " Jekyll's configuration file."